# communication issue between ACR122U-A2NR (nfc card reader) with samsung S2(Android 2.3.4)?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am trying to send following NDEF message from a windows application to Android phone through ACR122U-A2NR.

**43200001000000010100000027D101235402656E53746172742C4775696C6C61756D6520424552544541552C313233342C456E64**

On the windows end I'm sending NDEF message using following sequence of commands.
(For this I use winscard.dll).

1. "FF0000002DD48C0100000000004001FE0FBBBAA6C9890000000000000000FFFF01FE0FBBBAA
   6C98900000646666D01011000"
2. "FF00000002D486"
3. "FF00000015D48E0520060F636F6D2E616E64726F69642E6E7070"
4. "FF00000036D48E43200001000000010100000027D101235402656E53746172742C4775696C6C6
   1756D6520424552544541552C313233342C456E64"

Application on Nexus S android 2.3.4 is working fine. While same is not working on Samsung SII android 2.3.4.

In case of Nexus S command #4 returns "D58F00" (Success)
In case of SII above command returns "D58F25". Where "0x25" is error code for :
DEP protocol:Invalid device state the system is in state which does not allow this operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying this with ACS SDK or an alternative?
Have you checked nfctools library? http://www.grundid.de/nfc. I think they have better support for P2P communications since it fully implement the android protocols specification (although still have some bugs).

Comment: ON SG SII we have made communication using card emulation mode. we set ACR122 reader as ISO/IEC14443-4 PICC and it worked fine.

Comment: you can send commands to ACR122 card reader using winscard.dll,APDU should be above except first one is:
FF0000002DD48C4000000000004001FE0FBBBAA6C9890000000000000000FFFF01FE0FBBBAA 6C98900000646666D01011000